# How to send a message to a thread that is doing a lengthy operation?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have a main thread, and a worker thread. When the main thread is about to terminate, I need to send a message to the worker thread so it can terminate itself cleanly (I have heard that `TerminateThread()` is a bad idea).

The worker thread will be doing a lengthy operation (that will take more than 30 seconds), so is there a way to send it a message while doing this lengthy operation somehow. Or maybe the design of my program is wrong and a worker thread should not be doing such length operations?

Comment: When your main thread is about to terminate, set some flag to 1 and check that flag periodically in the worker thread, so the worker thread can terminate gracefully as soon as your flag is 1.

Comment: The worker thread needs to check a cancellation token at suitably frequent intervals

Comment: @David Heffernan So if a worker thread expects a message to be sent to it, then it should not make operations that take a long time, or maybe break this lengthy operation into small steps that allows me to place the flag checking between them?

Answer (score 2):

As a general principle, do not terminate threads.

Your background worker thread can periodically check if the program wants to exit. You should use `std::atomic<bool>` to do that. Here is an example on how to use it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

volatile std::atomic<bool> g_bExit(false);

void thread1()
{
   while( !g_bExit )
   {
      // do stuff here
   }
}

int main()
{
      std::thread th1(thread1);

      g_bExit = true;

      th1.join() ; // wait for thread
}
```

Comment: This is not a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys. I've updated my answer to provide detailed explanation.

Comment: Surely, you meant to write `volatile std::atomic<bool> g_bExit(false);`

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution, but maybe not the best one is to use a global flag variable, initially with 0 value.

When the main thread finishes set it to one. Your other thread should check for this variable in a loop.

when the variable is 1 then the thread knows that the main thread has finished.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Synchronization is still needed to avoid race conditions. Polling for variable change isn't good design, as it will hog CPU. Or delayed polling will cause message to be processed late (that too with random timing)

Answer (score 0):

Use `PostThreadMessage` function to post a message to another thread. Another thread must be having message pump (not necessarily a GUI-message-pump). Use `GetMessage` in target thread to retrieve the message. You need to craft a structure (better approach), and send the structure object. Your structure would contain actual message type (Start, Message, Stop etc - set of enum values for example).

Or you may use new threading techniques of C++14 or use `unbounded_buffer` of VC++ concurrency runtime.  You need to explore and find appropriate solution for your problem.

I didn't post any example, since this domain is quite large. You better search on the web for examples, references etc.

**EDIT**: I believe I have misunderstood the problem initially. Here is my solution: Use event synchronization object. In worker thread, wait for event through `WaitForSingeObject` (or `WaitForMultipleObjects`). From source thread call `SetEvent` on same synchronization object. Yes, there are new alternatives in C++ `std::thread`

Comment: What if the other thread doesn't want to run a message loop. It's quite rare for worker threads to do that.

Comment: Messages posted with `PostThreadMessage` get lost, if the receiving thread happens to be in a modal message loop. No error messages, no exceptions, nothing. They silently get swallowed. See [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx) for additional info.

Comment: I have never faced messages getting lost. And what modal-message-loop is? You meant a UI thread running? No, it will be a non-UI worker thread. BTW, yes there are better and newer approaches for "producer-consumer" pattern, and PTM is the most basic one to learn and use.

Comment: Once you call a user32.dll function on a thread, that thread is turned into a fully fledged GUI thread, with message queues, input queues, etc. Your wish, that *"this will be a non-UI worker thread"* cannot be enforced statically or at runtime. It's a prayer, at best, and faith-based programming hasn't quite made it mainstream yet.

Comment: There are pitfalls using PTM approach... but can you give reference to the fact that calling any user32.dll function makes it full-fledged UI thread. I strongly distrust this fact.

Comment: @IInspectable I think you might be making too much of this. It's a worker thread. It simply is not going to show a modal dialog. Were it to do so, then missing thread messages is the very least of your worries.

Comment: That's hardly important, Ajay. Once you call one of the message retrieval functions, your thread surely will have a message queue. In other words: It is a GUI thread. @David: This cannot be enforced. Of course you don't start out with a buggy implementation. Yet, when the feature request comes along to notify the user about finished calculations, someone will simply call `MessageBox`. Next you know, you have a bug report that occasionally the application deadlocks on shutdown.

Comment: @IInspectable I disagree. Your scenaro relies on the existence of a worse bug. You are cutting your hand off to spite your face. The real problem here is that using the message queue forces the thread to service the queue. Which it likely won't want to do, and will find to be very awkward. A cancellation token, e.g. an event or atomic bool is what's needed.

Comment: @David: I was commenting on the proposed answer. While you raise valid points, why `PostThreadMessage` may be inappropriate, I outlined the conditions under which it flat out fails.

Comment: @IInspectable, We had producer-consumer implementation on a banking/finance server, on top of PTM, and it never ever failed, no message got lost ever. We needed to implement our custom implementation (before C++11, new threading era) only after we found that after 10k posted (unprocessed) messages, message-queue wont take more. PTM is not a bad design. Calling user32.dll function doesn't create a message pump - only GetMessage call will do it.

Comment: @Ajay: Neither will create a message pump. Either one will create a message queue, if it doesn't exist already. The *"it never failed"* mantra is mostly moot. I pointed out the precise conditions under which messages posted to a thread are lost. You are arguing against logic. I'm done.